# Laravel Vue - Store Array

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, post

I want to store data from array to my Database. My code looks like this:

**Vue.js**

```
const self = this;
fetch('/api/store/devices',{
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(self.devices),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // do something
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

**API Route**

```
Route::post('store/devices',[App\Http\Controllers\StorageController::class, 'store']);
```

**StorageController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Go to array and save data
}
```

The data i overget looks like this:

```
[
  {device_id: "1245678", storage_id: 1},
  {device_id: "8784889", storage_id: 1},
  {device_id: "8457875", storage_id: 1}
]
```

How can i store this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend to put the array into a field in order to make an ["Open to extension, close to modification"](https://stackify.com/solid-design-open-closed-principle/) api:

```json
{
  'devices': [
    {device_id: "1245678", storage_id: 1},
    {device_id: "8784889", storage_id: 1},
    {device_id: "8457875", storage_id: 1}
  ]
}
```

Secondly, if you are trying to save a relationship instance between a device and a storage, you should use [laravel relationship methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models).

If its an individual model info, try the next code.

You must iterate all devices and create it as your laravel model:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->devices as $device) {
        YourModel::create($device); // if you had set $fillable attribute on your model

        // or like this
        $yourModel = new YourModel();
        $yourModel->device_id = $device['device_id'];
        $yourModel->storage_id = $device['storage_id'];
        $yourModel->save(); // it saves yourModel into your db
    }
}
```

YourModel [fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) example:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

<?php
class YourModel extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'device_id',
        'storage_id',
    ];
}
```